# Safari foreignObject tag without uppercase in devtools

Tags: svg, safari, foreignobject

I'm using the foreignObject tag inside an SVG, which is working on Chrome, however, it isn't working on Safari. I have gone through about 20 solutions, but the issue persists.

One of the solutions was a user mistyping `foreignObject`, they instead wrote it as `foreignobject` (lowercase "O").

In my code, foreignObject is spelled with the correct casing, **however**, in Safari's devtools, I notice that the tag is spelled `foreignobject`!

(Below, Safari devtools screenshot, and my code screenshot)

[image]

[image]

I'm sure this is what is causing the issue I'm having, but it makes no sense, since I have it written correctly in the code, but it's misread when Safari builds the site.

Is there any precedence for something like this? What can I do to change this misreading of my element tag name?

Comment: Code should be posted as text not images and you really need a [mcve] here rather than just one element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the `xmlns` attribute of your `<foreignObject>` to the XHTML name-space. Safari will thus consider it an HTML element when the SVG document is served as a standalone (if it was served inline in an HTML document, then they'd discard it.
This attribute must be set on the top **HTML** element, that is on the `<foreignObject>` content:

```html
<foreignObject
  requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"
  width="300"
  height="100"
  >
    <html-elem xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...
```

(Note that when served inline in an HTML document, Safari's web-dev tools will also show this element lower-cased, even though it will work correctly).

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. Strangely enough, I had it without the ```xmlns``` attribute earlier, and added it in to see if it will work. Upon removing the ```xmlns``` AND ```requiredFeatures``` (the way I had it before, the video is now visible, although the size and positioning are WAY off. Do you know what I can do about this?

Comment: change your x and y attributes

Comment: when I highlight the element itself, it's the highlight is perfectly positioned (x and y). The video plays in the bottom right corner, half off the side of the screen, however.